# Member specialization for a templated class for groups of types?

Tags: c++, class, templates, object, matrix

I have a matrix class and I want to print the matrix to the terminal differently for different matrix types (int, float, double). I want to achieve this:

- If the matrix type if `int`, print matrix using `printf("%d ",matrix[i][j])`
- If the matrix type if `float` or `double`, print matrix using `printf("%.3f ",matrix[i][j])`
- Otherwise, throw an error

Here are the relevant parts of what I have:

```
...

template <class T>
class Matrix2D {
private:
    std::vector< std::vector<T> > matrix;
public:
    ...
    void print() const; // print the whole matrix
}

...

template <class T>
void Matrix2D<T>::print() const {
    // throw an error
}

template <>
void Matrix2D<int>::print() const {
    // print matrix using printf("%d ",matrix[i][j])
}

template <>
void Matrix2D<float,double>::print() const {
    // print matrix using printf("%.3f ",matrix[i][j])
}
```

But using `Matrix2D<float,double>` gives me the error message `error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)`. I want, however, to have a common `print()` function for both `float` and `double` type matrices (don't want to copy the same thing twice). What is the simplest way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just as an alternative to proposed templated solutions, using old good function overloading:

```
public:
    void print() const
    {
        for (auto const& row : matrix)
            for (auto const& v : row)
                print(v);
    }

private:
    static void print(int val)
    {
        printf("%d ", val);
    }

    static void print(float val)
    {
        printf("%.3f", val);
    }
```

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it. It's a lightweight solution, avoiding extra libraries. I can write the bulk of my display function in one piece and call this overloaded print function which minimizes the extra code writing.

Answer (score 1):

The question as asked wants `Matrix2D<short>::print()` to throw an error. To achieve this you can use tag dispatching.

## Tags - simple

The naïve approach requires you to specialize tag for each type directly.

```
namespace detail
{

struct int_tag{};
struct float_tag{};
struct error_tag{};

template<typename T> struct choose_tag { using type = error_tag; };

template<> struct choose_tag<int> { using type = int_tag; };
template<> struct choose_tag<double> { using type = float_tag; };
template<> struct choose_tag<float> { using type = float_tag; };

template<typename T>
using tag = typename choose_tag<T>::type;

}
```

## Tags - type lists

You can avoid this with Boost.Hana (or other MPL solution). First, define check for a type in a list:

```
template<typename T, typename... Us>
constexpr bool contains =
        hana::any_of(hana::tuple_t<Us...>, hana::partial(hana::equal, hana::type_c<T>))();
```

Then just `enable_if` that type for your tags:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct choose_tag
{ using type = error_tag; };

template<typename T>
struct choose_tag<T, enable_if_t<contains<T, int>>>
{ using type = int_tag; };

template<typename T>
struct choose_tag<T, enable_if_t<contains<T, double, float>>>
{ using type = float_tag; };
```

## Common - `print` implementation

Then declare function templates that use them:

```
template<typename T>
void print_matrix(detail::int_tag, T&&) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print_matrix(detail::float_tag, T&&) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print_matrix(detail::error_tag, T&&) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}
```

and call:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix2D {
private:
    std::vector< std::vector<T> > matrix;
public:

    void print() const {
        print_matrix(detail::tag<T>{}, *this);
    }
};
```

Here's are live examples of [simple](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WHIfhup7IeWbyMMv) and [type list](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6Yz1WMapKLQzsSKC) versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enable_if` and [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types), do do something like this:

```
template<class T> class MyClass
{
public:
    // this one will be created if the argument is of a floating point type, i.e.
    // double or float
    template<typename U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, void>::type
    print(U v)
    {
        std::cout << "float" << std::endl;
    }

    // this one will be created if the argument is of an integral type, i.e.
    // bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, short, int, long, long long
    template<typename U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value, void>::type
    print(U v)
    {
        std::cout << "integer" << std::endl;
    }

};


int main() {
    MyClass<int>c;
    c.print(1);
    c.print(1.f);
}
```

Output:

```
integer
float
```